# Filter data in django admin page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have a django project, in one of admin pages I'm adding data to the table
[image: Adding page]

And I want after I choose one of themes, in Students name will be only students enrolled for this theme. How I can filter them by theme name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not do this out of the box.  One third-party package I often see recommended to accomplish this common task (as opposed to writing your own ajax to do it) is [django smart selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects).